# How to refer child component name in parent component LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have a child component folder "bCPContractTOP" which has

1. bCPContractTOP.HTML
2. bCPContractTOP.js
3. bCPContractTOP.js-meta.xml

How to call this from parent component. I am getting one error

**LWC1010: Failed to resolve entry for module "bCPContractTOP".**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <lightning-input type="text" value={checknameinputvalue} name="CheckName" label="Check Name" required onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-button label="Generate" title="Generate" class="slds-m-left_x-small" onclick={handleClick} ></lightning-button>
    <c-bCPContractTOP check-name={checkNameValue}></c-bCPContractTOP>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Capital letters become lowercased and prefixed with a hyphen (`-`), so the name would become:

```
c-b-c-p-contract-t-o-p
```

Your code would look like this:

```
<c-b-c-p-contract-t-o-p check-name={checkNameValue}></c-b-c-p-contract-t-o-p>
```

This is called "kebab case" in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_components_folder).

For this reason, it's probably more beneficial to not use so many capital letters in your component name.

Also, the file names are case sensitive--make sure your template is `bCPContractTOP.html` (lowercase `html`).

Comment: Worth noting that numbers get a hyphen prefix too. (Not sure if each digit gets one, or just the first digit in a number sequence; didn't think to try that one out before.)